# Graphql for complex data structures

Tags: api, asp.net-web-api, graphql

Is there any level of complexity where GraphQL is not a suitable solution, for example when data structures are quite complex and have many interrelations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be surprised if anyone has come close to Facebook's scale of GraphQL usage yet, which is reported to have many thousands of types. So i'm going to have to guess that for practical purposes, the answer is no.